# onFling gesture not working on an Activity that has a TabHost

Tags: android

I been trying to add a onFling Gesture to an Activity that is composed by a TabHost.

I built my tabs usign xml with TabWidget. Here is my code

activity1.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/establecimientoView">

<TabHost 
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

         <TabWidget android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@android:id/tabs" />

         <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" >


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabIdEst"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                 <include layout="@layout/identificacion_establecimiento"/>

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabRefGeo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                 <include layout="@layout/referencia_geografica"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabUbicEstablecimiento"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                 <include layout="@layout/ubicacion_establecimiento"/>
            </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabVialidades"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                 <include layout="@layout/entre_vialidades"/>
            </LinearLayout>

         </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity1.java

```
public class EstablecimientoActivity extends Activity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener{
    TextView lblE90; 
    TextView lblExxGastos;
     TabHost tabs;

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.establecimiento);

           mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, this, null);

           initTabGroup();


           View establecimientoView = findViewById(R.id.establecimientoView);

           establecimientoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                        Log.d("On touch", "view establecimiento");
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });




     }

    private void initTabGroup(){

            tabs=(TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
            tabs.setup();

            TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tabIdEst");
            spec.setContent(R.id.tabIdEst);
            spec.setIndicator("Identificación del Establecimiento");
            tabs.addTab(spec);

            spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tabRefGeo");
            spec.setContent(R.id.tabRefGeo);
            spec.setIndicator("Referencia Geográfica");
            tabs.addTab(spec);

            spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tabUbEst");
            spec.setContent(R.id.tabUbicEstablecimiento);
            spec.setIndicator("Ubicación Establecimiento");
            tabs.addTab(spec);

            spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tabVialidades");
            spec.setContent(R.id.tabVialidades);
            spec.setIndicator("Entre Vialidades");
            tabs.addTab(spec);


            tabs.setCurrentTab(0);

    }



    // Listeners
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent arg0) {
        Log.d("onDown", "Tap");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        Log.d("onFling", e1.toString());

        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {
            return false;
        }

        // right to left swipe
        if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            Log.d("onFling","right to left");
            Intent intent = new Intent(this.getBaseContext(),
                    Activity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,
                    R.anim.slide_out_left);
            // left to right swipe
        } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            Log.d("onFling","left to right");

            this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,
                    R.anim.slide_out_right);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent arg0, MotionEvent arg1, float arg2,
            float arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

I been doing some research and I only get how swipe between tabs.
I just want to go to another activity, I mean I want to go from Activity1(contains the tabhost) to Activity2

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Horizontal Pager](https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager), specifically the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method inside [HorizontalPager.java](https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager/blob/master/src/com/github/ysamlan/horizontalpager/HorizontalPager.java). Instead of scrolling the page horizontally start a new activity.